# How can I cut the listview on the mask?

Tags: android, listview, mask, clip

I'm new in development on android. Please help me.
[image]

The left image is what it is currently doing, and the right is what I'd like. Red - ListView, Gray - Background of relativelayout

Comment: I think that what he's asking is relatively clear. Maybe a little bit more information would help. He wants to put a mask on top of the list view I guess.

Comment: If the background is of the relative layout, you're obviously NOT going to be able to cover the listview that is ON TOP. You will have to add another component that covers your listview.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a component on top of it. Here's a simple solution with a supplied arch image to cover part of the list. You will need to supply your own arch image.

Pic:

[image]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
  android:id="@+id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
</ListView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/arch" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You will have to make a shape drawing and add that to the root layout.